# continuity and differentiability in the origin of f(x,y)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have this function:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin(x^2y^2)^\alpha}{x^2y+y^3}&y\ne0,\\
x&y=0.
\end{cases}
$$

to prove continuity in $(0,0)$ can I use polar coordinates?
$|f(x,y)|\le \frac{(x^2y^2)^\alpha}{y(x^2+y^2)}$=$r^{4\alpha-3}|cos\theta|^{2\alpha} |sin\theta|^{2\alpha-1}\rightarrow0$ for $\alpha >{3 \over 4}$
But if $\alpha\le{3 \over 4}?$

Comment: You can use l'Hôpital's rule. Don't need polar coordinates

Comment: But it's a function in two variables

Comment: It seems that there is a sort of L'Hospital's rule for multi-variable limits [Check it out](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0363.pdf)

Comment: @GiulyB I think yes. $|f(x,y)|\le \frac{(x^2y^2)^\alpha}{y(x^2+y^2)}$=$r^{4\alpha-3}|cos\theta|^{2\alpha} |sin\theta|^{2\alpha-1}<r^{4\alpha-3}\to0$ for $\alpha >{3 \over 4}$